# Scrap dynamic elements in web page with Python - where to scroll and stop?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to scrap a website with dynamic elements. It looks like elements are loaded (and visible in the source code) as I scroll the page, within the same classes, but it changes every 6 to 8 elements it seems.

https://airtable.com/shrKma4KotuPyD1sp/tbleDyE2p94ind1eA
(it is a public page, I am allowed to scrap it)

I have found how to get the 8 first elements, but all the docs I found showed how to scroll to the bottom of the page - but I'd like to know if there is a way to scroll until elements in certain classes change, then repeat the process until the bottom of the page is hit?

I am using Python and Selenium.

Comment: Perhaps you could make a fnc that scrolls to **x** height and uses selenium's `WebDriverWait` class to wait until a given a element is present in the DOM.

Comment: You might also want to change your web scraping approach. Using my browser's Dev Tools I found that the website makes a GET request to a URL and the response is a JSON file containing all (i.e. 462) the cards (and their data). So, you can use python's `request` module to send the GET request and receive the response. You can use [this article](https://scrapecrow.com/reverse-engineering-intro.html) as a reference.

Comment: thanks a lot! it was actually easier than I thought then. I'll have a look at the article. From your experience, is it something you'd often see? or am I just lucky on this one?

Comment: Yes, you can often find the data you want by looking at the requests the websites makes. I'll add a script that sends the GET request for the JSON file I previously mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

##### Code for getting and saving JSON that contains the data you want:

```
import requests
import json

def get_json_string(url, req_headers=None, req_cookies=None):
    response = requests.get(url, headers=my_headers, cookies=req_cookies)

    # make request json obj
    json_obj = response.json()

    # make json obj into json string
    json_string = json.dumps(json_obj, indent=4)
    return json_string

def save_json(path, json_string):
    
    with open(path, mode='w') as file:
        file.write(json_string)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # URL for JSON file
    url = "https://airtable.com/v0.3/view/viwPQgpRQ4SmRDOcN/readSharedViewData?stringifiedObjectParams=%7B%22shouldUseNestedResponseFormat%22%3Atrue%7D&requestId=reqZ8CcUMBEbCQcjC&accessPolicy=%7B%22allowedActions%22%3A%5B%7B%22modelClassName%22%3A%22view%22%2C%22modelIdSelector%22%3A%22viwPQgpRQ4SmRDOcN%22%2C%22action%22%3A%22readSharedViewData%22%7D%2C%7B%22modelClassName%22%3A%22view%22%2C%22modelIdSelector%22%3A%22viwPQgpRQ4SmRDOcN%22%2C%22action%22%3A%22getMetadataForPrinting%22%7D%2C%7B%22modelClassName%22%3A%22view%22%2C%22modelIdSelector%22%3A%22viwPQgpRQ4SmRDOcN%22%2C%22action%22%3A%22readSignedAttachmentUrls%22%7D%2C%7B%22modelClassName%22%3A%22row%22%2C%22modelIdSelector%22%3A%22rows%20*%5BdisplayedInView%3DviwPQgpRQ4SmRDOcN%5D%22%2C%22action%22%3A%22createBoxDocumentSession%22%7D%2C%7B%22modelClassName%22%3A%22row%22%2C%22modelIdSelector%22%3A%22rows%20*%5BdisplayedInView%3DviwPQgpRQ4SmRDOcN%5D%22%2C%22action%22%3A%22createDocumentPreviewSession%22%7D%5D%2C%22shareId%22%3A%22shrKma4KotuPyD1sp%22%2C%22applicationId%22%3A%22app7crtuSadIBDrF8%22%2C%22generationNumber%22%3A0%2C%22expires%22%3A%222023-04-13T00%3A00%3A00.000Z%22%2C%22signature%22%3A%22d2d3e7ce7788e3a594c5afa819943de1714a088a7ef5d3d9630888188e4e9590%22%7D"

    my_headers = {
        
        "Host": "airtable.com",
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/111.0",
        "Accept": "*/*",
        "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
        "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
        "x-early-prefetch": "true",
        "x-user-locale": "en",
        "x-airtable-application-id": "app7crtuSadIBDrF8",
        "x-airtable-page-load-id": "pglzCAPUzY3PBtt1w",
        "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
        "x-airtable-inter-service-client": "webClient",
        "x-time-zone": "", # ADD YOUR LOCATION VALUE
        "DNT": "1",
        "Connection": "keep-alive",
        "Sec-Fetch-Dest": "empty",
        "Sec-Fetch-Mode": "cors",
        "Sec-Fetch-Site": "same-origin",
        "TE": "trailers"
    }

    json_string = get_json_string(url, my_headers)

    # save json as file
    path = "C:/Users/uber/RandomScripts/data/airtable_data.json"
    save_json(path, json_string)
```

##### How I found the GET request for the JSON file:

[image]

You might [this article](https://scrapecrow.com/reverse-engineering-intro.html) about web scraping by means of "reverse engineering" the website's requests helpful.